# is it necessary to return a different object from the getter method than the object passed by Hibernate to the setter?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa

I recently came accross the following statement on **Java persistence with Hibernate** book.I was able to understand everything else  except the highlighted one.

*Another issue to consider is dirty checking. Hibernate automatically detects
object state changes in order to synchronize the updated state with the database.
**It’s usually safe to return a different object from the getter method than the
object passed by Hibernate to the setter.** Hibernate compares the objects by
value—not by object identity—to determine whether the property’s persistent
state needs to be updated. For example, the following getter method doesn’t
result in unnecessary SQL UPDATEs:*

```
public String getFirstname() {
return new String(firstname);
}
```

**Query:** My concern here is we are creating **new** instance. Is that really necessary? kindly correct me if i'm wrong here..

Comment: It's saying it's safe to use a Transfer Object (or Value Object), and that Hibernate will consider the object by value (not object identity). That `new String()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you will return different object from getter this means you are trying to create a defensive copy.
From hibernate perspective if you return different object from getter that object will have no history with hibernate session, and if you will call save on that object and that object already exist in database you will have `ConstraintViolationException`, you have to call `saveOrUpdate` instead. Call to `saveOrUpdate` will cause hibernate to issue select statement to database before committing.

if some object was already in session and you call commit after performing some changes Hibernate will issue update query

Comment: how does this sentence relate to dirty checking? " It’s usually safe to return a different object from the getter method than the object passed by Hibernate to the setter."